# Select with list as parameter and if it is empty select with no parameter in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, conditional-statements, arguments

I have a `PostgreSQL` database with a food table and a tag table. I need to query data from a `Python` GUI based on the tag(s) using `psycopg3`. If the tag argument is an empty list, I need to use data from all of the restaurants in the food table.

The query below returns the desired result if some of the restaurant(s) with argument id(s) (`'ids_arg'`) have some of the argument tag(s) (`'tags_arg'`). How can I query and compute the data from all the restaurants regradless of ids or tags if the `'tags_arg'` list is empty, resulting in `t.name = ANY (array[]::text[])` in PostgreSQL? I can get the desired result by adding a `UNION ALL` with the same query without the `INNER JOIN` and using the first or second row of the result table depending on the results but that approximately doubles the lines in the query string file. It matters considering readability. Is there a neat way of achieving the same result without the `UNION ALL` or otherwise adding a significant amount of lines? Efficiency analysis would also be appreciated.

```
SELECT Total, Total - Drinks AS "Without drinks", Drinks   
FROM (
  SELECT 
  SUM (f.prepared) 
  FILTER (
    WHERE f.date BETWEEN 'first' AND 'last'
    AND f.restaurant_id = ANY ('ids_arg')
  ) AS Total,
  SUM (f.prepared)
  FILTER (
    WHERE (f.product_id = 10 OR f.product_id = 17) 
    AND f.date BETWEEN 'first' AND 'last'
    AND f.restaurant_id = ANY ('ids_arg')
  ) AS Drinks
  FROM food f
  INNER JOIN tags t 
  ON t.restaurant_id = f.restaurant_id 
  WHERE t.name = ANY ('tags_arg'::text[])
);
```

EDIT: here is a [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/KPRb6NeB) with the `UNION ALL` queries and Zegarek's answer queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an adequate condition to your `where`:

```sql
SELECT Total, Total - Drinks AS "Without drinks", Drinks   
FROM (
  SELECT 
  SUM (f.prepared) 
  FILTER (
    WHERE f.date BETWEEN 'first' AND 'last'
    AND f.restaurant_id = ANY ('ids_arg')
  ) AS Total,
  SUM (f.prepared)
  FILTER (
    WHERE (f.product_id = 10 OR f.product_id = 17) 
    AND f.date BETWEEN 'first' AND 'last'
    AND f.restaurant_id = ANY ('ids_arg')
  ) AS Drinks
  FROM food f
  INNER JOIN tags t 
  ON t.restaurant_id = f.restaurant_id 
  WHERE array_position('tags_arg'::text[],t.name) IS NOT null 
     OR array_length('tags_arg'::text[],1) IS null
);
```

This also makes it null-safe. A regular [`any(text[])` yields a `null`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparisons.html#FUNCTIONS-COMPARISONS-ANY-SOME) regardless of whether your `t.name` is in the `tags_arg` array or not, as long as there's one or more `null`s also present in the array, or `t.name` itself is a null, or both. That's because `any()` uses regular equality `=` operator, while [`array_position()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html#id-1.5.8.25.6.2.2.8.1.1.1) uses [`is not distinct from`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparison.html#FUNCTIONS-COMPARISON-PRED-TABLE) construct.

Here's a cheatsheet: [demo at db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/8T91Pz_N)

```
select tags_arg,
       tags_arg::text[] as_array,
       'tag1'=any(tags_arg::text[])                                 as "base",
       'tag1'=any(coalesce(tags_arg::text[],array['tag1']::text[])) as "+coalesce()",
       'tag1'=any(coalesce(tags_arg::text[],array['tag1']::text[]))
            OR array_length(tags_arg::text[],1) is null             as "+coalesce()+OR",
       'tag1'=any(coalesce(tags_arg::text[],array['tag1']::text[]))
            OR array_length(tags_arg::text[],1) is null
            OR array_position(tags_arg::text[],null) is not null    as "+coalesce()+OR+nullsafe",
       array_position(tags_arg::text[],'tag1') is not null 
            OR array_length(tags_arg::text[],1) is null             as "final"
from (values  ('{tag1,tag2,tag3}') --matching array
             ,('{tag4,tag5}')      --non-matching array
             ,('{tag6,null}')      --non-matching with a null
             ,('{null}')           --only a null
             ,('{}')               --empty
             ,(null)              ) as args(tags_arg);
```

| tags_arg | as_array | base | +coalesce() | +coalesce()+OR | +coalesce()+OR+nullsafe | final |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| {tag1,tag2,tag3} | {tag1,tag2,tag3} | **T** | **T** | **T** | **T** | **T** |
| {tag4,tag5} | {tag4,tag5} | f | f | f | f | f |
| {tag6,null} | {tag6,NULL} | *null* | *null* | *null* | **T** | f |
| {null} | {NULL} | *null* | *null* | *null* | **T** | f |
| {} | {} | f | f | **T** | **T** | **T** |
| *null* | *null* | *null* | **T** | **T** | **T** | **T** |

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. It seems to work when tags are provided but I get an erroneous result when there are no tags, i.e. when the argument to `any` is `array[]::text[]`. Please see this dbfidde: https://dbfiddle.uk/m_C42IYa

Comment: @jvkloc You made my suggestion into additional `JOIN` conditions instead of a `WHERE` condition, which won't work the same: [demo at the end](https://dbfiddle.uk/qj8xLqsx?hide=64). It would help if you aligned the identifiers, types and sample values in your question with the ones in your fiddle. It would also help if you presented a very small and simple test with *minimum* data needed to reproduce the case and little noise - the hundreds of what looks like real-life rows don't aid readability.

Comment: Ok so `and` and `where` refer to different things after `join`. I inferrred from some earlier exmples that I should use `and` after `join` to make it work. I'll study your examples again. And I'll try to make the question and fiddle compatible. Thanks for the lesson!

Comment: @jvkloc Sometimes it makes no logical difference whether you add conditions to `join` or to `where`, but here it does, at least the way you did. I assume only the `restaurant_id` was meant to join rows, from among which you wanted to keep/discard some based on array overlap. Adding that to `join` freed the rows from having to match on `restaurant_id` whenever the array was empty or null ([`c1 AND c2 OR c3` means if `c3 is true`, c1 and c2 don't matter](https://dbfiddle.uk/Nak2-GLI)). You can fix that with `c1 AND (c2 OR c3)`: [demo at the end](https://dbfiddle.uk/bJQK4LJ9?hide=128)